# Conversion from vb.net String to DB2 Timestamp

Tags: vb.net, db2

I'm really frustated right now, because I just can't manage to get a VB.NET manually created DATE datatype into a DB2 column which is has the TIMESTAMP datatype.

I tried a few different ways to handle this, but no matter what I do I always get the error "SQL0180N: The syntax of the string representation of a datetime value is incorrect".

The part in my application which handles the conversion from String to DATE is right here:

```
Dim neuesDatum As Date
neuesDatum = CDate(jahr & "-" & "0" & monat & "-01 00:00:00")
```

The String for the conversion looks like this: 2013-01-01 00:00:00

I also tried the german format of a date (01.01.203), tried to use the String without the last part (00:00:00), but no matter what I do it always ends up the same way.

I use a Stored Procedure to insert the Data into a Table. The Date is delivered as the parameter "SollMonat".

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "ADDON21C"."STP_BEITRAGSSATZ_ADD"
(
        IN @Id BIGINT,
        IN @Typ VARCHAR(100),
        **IN @SollMonat TIMESTAMP,**
        IN @G VARCHAR(100),
        IN @F VARCHAR(100),
        IN @H VARCHAR(100),
        IN @U1 VARCHAR(100),
        IN @U2 VARCHAR(100),
        IN @U1erhoeht VARCHAR(100),
        IN @U1ermaessigt VARCHAR(100),
        IN @RV VARCHAR(100),
        IN @ALV VARCHAR(100),
        IN @P VARCHAR(100),
        IN @RVgf VARCHAR(100),
        IN @KVgf VARCHAR(100),
        IN @ZusatzKV VARCHAR(100),
        IN @ZusatzPV VARCHAR(100),
        IN @Inso VARCHAR(100),
        OUT @result BIGINT
)
LANGUAGE SQL
SPECIFIC SQL12080109131643
BEGIN

        IF @Id IS NULL OR @Id = 0
        THEN
                INSERT INTO "ADDON21C".BS
                (Typ, Sollmonat, G, F, H, U1, U2, U1erhoeht, U1ermaessigt)
                VALUES
                (@Typ, @SollMonat, @G, @F, @H, @U1, @U2, @U1erhoeht, @U1ermaessigt);
                 SET @result = IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL();
        END IF;

END
```

The datatype for "Sollmonat" inside of the datatable is TIMESTAMP, too.

Guys, I would be very happy if you can help me out here. I'm completely out of ideas and no, I can't save the date as a VARCHAR in the table. Saving is as DATE in the database might be possible, but I believe I'd have the same problem there.

Thanks in advance!

@Steve It would only make the whole thing more confusing, because I build myself a few classes that allow me to map classes into datatables, but be assured that this isn't what screws this up. When I use a not manually created date, like Date.Now for example, it works fine.

Comment: Could you show the code where you pass the TIMESTAMP value to the underlying stored procedure?

Comment: Won't a simple `CAST(@SollMonat As TIMESTAMP)` do this?

Comment: No, the cast doesn't help. Still same error.

Comment: Have you tried to add the millisecond precision part to your data? TIMESTAMP stores also the [milliseconds precision](http://www.craigsmullins.com/dbu_1200.htm)

Comment: Yea, I can't even converse the String to a Date inside the vb.net application like this. Sad stuff :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you might try this. One is specifically saying that your parameter is a timestamp, and pass in the `Date` type:

```
cmdDB2.Parameters.Add("@SollMonat", DB2Type.Timestamp).Value = neuesDatum
```

Another possibility is defining the correct string representation of a date, and then using `.ToString()`. Below are a couple format strings, use the one that match your database's data type.

```
Private Const DB2_TSTAMP = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.ffffff"
Private Const DB2_DATE = "MM/dd/yyyy"

cmdDB2.Parameters.Add("@SollMonat", neuesDatum.ToString(DB2_TSTAMP))
```

These options have worked for me in the past. The timestamp format string should work all the time (it is the ODBC standard for a timestamp), but the date format string may vary by location, have a look at [this article in Information Center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008474.html).

Comment: Sigh .. unfortunately the "parameter-adding" is kind of dynamic. So I can't do stuff like this. You are on the right track though. Just noticed that the "manual date" doesn't have the hours, minutes and seconds. I think the only way to do this is to make a String out of the date. Didn't wanted to do that though. :/